# PostreSQL filter results by subset of a joined table and group them

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table of people, another table of cars and a third table to join them since they have a many to many relationship. I want to select people who own a certain set of cars and group them by a region property on the person. So for example I would want to find all American's who own a Honda and a Nissan.

Example:

```
people table
id  name  region
1   Jon   America
2   Jane  Europe
3   Mike  America
```

```
cars table
id  make
1  Honda
2  Toyota
3  Nissan
```

```
people_cars table
person_id  car_id
1          1
1          3
2          2
3          1
```

```
Desired result:
region    own_honda_and_nissan
America   1
Europe    0
```

An idea for a SQL expression I have is:

```
SELECT
    people.region,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN cars.name IN ('Honda', 'Nissan') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS own_honda_and_nissan
FROM people
JOIN people_cars ON people_cars.person_id = people.id
JOIN cars ON people_cars.car_id = cars.id
GROUP BY people.region
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN cars.name IN ('Honda', 'Nissan') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
ORDER BY own_honda_and_nissan DESC
```

This works if you group by people.id but once they get grouped by region it no longer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT p.pregion, COUNT(*) as own_honda_and_nissan
FROM (SELECT pid, p.region,
      FROM people p JOIN
           people_cars pc
           ON pc.person_id = p.id JOIN
           cars c
           ON pc.car_id = c.id
      WHERE c.name IN ('Honda', 'Nissan')
      GROUP BY p.id, p.region
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.name) = 2
     ) p
GROUP BY p.region
ORDER BY own_honda_and_nissan DESC
```